# USB Debugging not working on galaxy s 2 android 4.1.2

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, eclipse-adt, usb-debugging

I was able to debug to my phone directly before long time, but recently it seems like it doesn't work

it works fine with AVD but the My device it doesn't work

it **(doesn't display the debugging screen)** on my  device when I plug in the USB.

also I got an

- **OS Windows 7 64 bit Service Pack 1**

  - I have restart Eclips , and windows 9999999999999 times still nothing change
  - Processor Intel I5-2500K
  - Ram 8GB
  - **No antivirus program** installed or **firewalls** (just the original one from Microsoft)
  - .
- **My device is Samsung Galaxy S 2**

  - I have **installed the latest usb drivers** from samsung and also **latest version of KIES program**
  - Android Version 4.1.2 **Stock Rom** , Baseband version  **I9100DXLS8**
  - rooted
  - Developer Option **'ON'**
  - USB debugging **(checked/tick)**.
  - Stay awake **(Checked/tick)**
  - .
- **Eclips (ADT) From android website**

  - version **v22.30-887826**
  - **SDK latest update** and everything installed (even **Google USB Driver**)
  - On **Android Device Chooser** my device is listed
  - Using **'adb devices'** my device is listed
  - I have tried **kill and start server** using **adb**
  - this is an screen shoot for **adb** and **android device chooser**

    - https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3zpl.png
  - when I try to run any project I get an error message

this is cordova example error message on console (also for an empty project i get the same error)

```
[2014-01-04 22:42:13 - cordovaExample] ------------------------------
[2014-01-04 22:42:13 - cordovaExample] Android Launch!
[2014-01-04 22:42:13 - cordovaExample] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-04 22:42:13 - cordovaExample] Performing org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample activity launch
[2014-01-04 22:42:13 - cordovaExample] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-01-04 22:42:17 - cordovaExample] Uploading cordovaExample.apk onto device '0019d14209756e'
[2014-01-04 22:42:17 - cordovaExample] Installing cordovaExample.apk...
[2014-01-04 22:42:18 - cordovaExample] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2014-01-04 22:42:18 - cordovaExample] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-01-04 22:42:18 - cordovaExample] Launch canceled!
```

and in LogCat

```
?:??: W/?(?): Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory
: E/(): Device disconnected: 1
```

Comment: Try Run > Run Configurations > Target and choose Always prompt to Pick A Device

Comment: @user666  it is actually always prompt, but I did what you have said and nothing change

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml please?

Comment: How about Windows device manager? does windows detects your device and has installed the appropriate driver?

Comment: @user666 if want to check android:debuggable="true" then yes I implemented that... sorry I'm not at home now to get the actual source

Comment: @gian1200 yes it detect as MTP and camera all works fine. actually as I said at the beginning I don't see the USB debugging screen in my phone when I plug it to the PC, I don't know why! but I'm sure 1000% that developer option and usb debugging are ON